# "Selected" item in a selection list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i have a select list in my website

```
<select name="Mem_BloodGr" >
<option value="A+">A+</option><option value="A-">A-</option>
<option value="B+">B+</option><option value="B-">B-</option>
<option value="O+">O+</option><option value="O-">O-</option>
<option value="AB+">AB+</option><option value="AB-">AB-</option>
</select>
```

i am doing my project in mvc4. when my page loades **@Model.Mem_BloodGroup** contains the item that saved in the sql database. I want to show that **@Model.Mem_BloodGroup item as the selected item in the dropdownlist** . How it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dropdown is not generated by a helper and if your model contains only the targeted blood group and if you're using jQuery, you can select the value with:

```
$('select[name="Mem_BloodGr"]').find('option[value="@Model.Mem_BloodGroup "]').attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Why using javascript for this???? You have server side helpers designed exactly for that purpose.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, agree. But the question did not reference any list of blood types, but rather a specific blood type, stored in the database (i.e. instance). As stated in the question `@Model.Mem_BloodGroup contains the item that saved in the sql database`.

Comment: The question didn't reference any list of blood types but that's so much obvious. Otherwise how would you even generate this `select` list? I hope he didn't hardcode the HTML :-) And if he has, then he totally should change his logic and use the helper that's designed exactly for this purpose. And if the items are not stored in the database they can easily be hardcoded as an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` value on the view model. That's the proper way to do dropdowns in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Seeing the `select` object listed like that, made me think it's hardcoded. The name of the model property suggested a single type. I don't know exactly what we did. I do totally agree, helpers are the way to go. It's not that difficult to include the list of (all 4) possible blood types in the Model...

Answer (score 3):

When rendering the DropDown use this model property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Mem_BloodGroup, Model.Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [**selected** attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

```
<select name="Mem_BloodGr" >
<option value="A+" selected>A+</option><option value="A-">A-</option>
<option value="B+">B+</option><option value="B-">B-</option>
<option value="O+">O+</option><option value="O-">O-</option>
<option value="AB+">AB+</option><option value="AB-">AB-</option>
</select>
```